# Do multiple insert in a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, multiple-insert

I need to do a multiple insert in a stored procedure with MySQL.
I've been looking about this but I didn't find almost any information or examples at all.

The number of messages (inserts) varies. Sometimes could be one, sometimes could be twenty.

In short, I need to do the following: let's say the users could belong to a group. If one of them leave the group, I need to advice about this action to the other users with a message.

The inserts would be something like this:

```
INSERT INTO messages (author, dest, title, msg)
VALUES (ldr,id1,'Same title for all messages','Same body message for all'),
(ldr,id2,'Same title for all messages','Same body message for all'),
...
```

I've tried to do it with single inserts into a loop but the time it lasts is, as you can guess, terribly high.

The possible ways I've thought or seen in other pages are:

- Take the ID's of the users into a text variable, prepare the insert statement with PREPARE and execute it.
- Take the ID's of the users, create a temporary table and introduce the ID's, and finally insert all the messages from there.
- Any other way to do it...¿?

I don't know which one of them is the best way to do it, in the sense of good practice and performance/efficiency.

Do you have any ideas?

In case you know how to do it, please, could you write a simple example?

Thank you so much.

Comment: `VALUES`  should be appear once in an INSERT query.

Comment: @Grijesh Chauhan Right, my mistake. It's already corrected.

Comment: You could split out `dest` to it's own table (message_id, dest), so only those would need to be added.

Comment: @Wrikken I don't understand what you mean. I already know which are the group of 'dest', if that was what you wanted to point out

Comment: No, I wanted to point out that you don't need to duplicate subject & bodies.

Comment: It depends a little on how the message is delivered, you might even want to employ 3 tables: `message`, `message_receivers`, but also `message_groups`. It all depends on how this is delivered further on: if in a site-context, you might want to search for messages to the user, but also to the groups the user belongs to. If it's a temporary location for email to send, the sending script will need to know how to expand group-ids to their individual receivers.

Comment: Ok Wrikken, I understand you, but it's more simple than that. Although the users belongs to a group, there're no shared messages. I mean, the messages are always sent to each user. The problem is that if a user deletes the message, the rest of the members of that group couldn't read the message anymore. And it's nothing about the email service. It's just about inserting a row that corresponds to a message.